# What happens to fourier transform of the sampled output of pure sinusoidal input of 26kHz if sampled with 44.1kHz sample frequency?

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing, sampling

Because pure sinusoidal signal only contains impulses, I was wondering what happens to the fourier transform of the sample output from the sinusoidal input of $26$kHz if the sampling is done with sample frequency of $44.1$kHz.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/19447/235) on dsp.SE.

Answer (score 0):

Because the sampling rate is less than two samples per cycle, the input will be aliased down to $26-44.1=-18.1$ kHz.  If the wave is a sine wave, the minus sign just inverts the signal.   If $t$ is a multiple of $1/(44.1$ kHz), $\sin (2\pi t 26$ kHz$)=\sin (-2\pi t 18.1$ kHz).  If you have a large duration, you will see (almost all the) energy in frequencies near to $-18.1$ kHz.  If you don't have an integral number of cycles, the discontinuity between the start and end of the interval will make other artifacts.